projections on minimal left ideals of semisimple algebras
Let $KG$ be a semisimple group algebra of a finite group $G$ over $K$. Consider $W=KGe$ as a minimal left ideal of this algebra and $e$ as a primitive idempotent. Here, $W$ is a simple left $KG$-module, and $D:=\text{End}_{KG}(W)$ is a $K$-division algebra by Schur's lemma. $D$ acts on $W$ as a ring of right operators of $W$, endowing $W$ with the structure of right $D$-vector space $W_D$.
Suppose $\rho:KG \to \text{End}_K(W^n)$ is a linear representation. I am wondering what the image of $\rho(e) \in \text{End}_K(W^n)$ is. $\rho(e)$ is a projection, but what is its image? Is it $D \otimes_K W$, $W \otimes_D D$, or $D^n$?
I am suspecting that $\text{rank}(\rho(e))=n \dim_K(D)$. Is it right? How can we prove this?
